# How can I automatically reboot a GCE instance after it crashes?

Tags: ubuntu, google-compute-engine

I think I want a shell script to automatically reboot an instance no matter if it crashes because of software problems or hardware problems.

The OS is Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 1):

There are likely going to be a number of solutions.  One that you might consider is to use Google Stackdriver Monitoring Up-time checks.  This allows you to define a measurement of a service/Compute Engine being "up" ... see:

https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/uptime-checks

If the compute engine does not respond (because it has crashed or is otherwise not available), this can cause an alert which can trigger a notification channel which can call a webhook that can use Compute Engine management API to stop or restart a Compute Engine.

Break your puzzle apart into separate pieces:

1. How do I detect that a Compute Engine is un-responsive or crashed?
2. How do I invoke some software / service / task / function that will perform custom logic?
3. How do I perform logic that will stop / restart a compute engine?

If you piece these parts together, you should have your solution.

Answer (score 0):

GCE provides Managed Instance Groups with Autohealing feature that could be useful for both stateless and stateful workloads.

In case of a stateful workload, if you expected your stateful workload could crash, you should implement preventive measures to protect data consistency like regular committing, keeping transaction logs on a fast reliable storage optimized for writing with the write-back cache disabled, snapshots, initdbscript, etc, pretty similar to what you used to do on bare-metal systems.

Next, you will need distinguishing healthchecks (As comprehensively advised by [Kolban](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60124088/11602913)). You should have separate health checks for load balancing and for autohealing.

Finally, create a MIG with healthchecks and Autohealing accordingly to your needs.

Please see

[Instance Groups: Autohealing](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/?hl=en_US&_ga=2.119450121.-1824181490.1559548035#autohealing)

[Setting up health checking and autohealing](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/autohealing-instances-in-migs)